# Equation of a straight line in the treated segments

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Problem: $$4x - 7y -2  = 0$$

But the real problem is that in my math book, the result of this is different than my solution.

This is my progress so far:

$$4x - 7y - 2 = 0$$
$$\frac{4x}{2} - \frac{7y}{2} = 1$$

This is result that should be:
$$
\frac{x}{1/2} + \frac{y}{-2/7} = 1
$$
My question is how this is possible?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: $a= \frac{1}{1/a}$ for any $a \neq 0$.

Comment: $x/a+y/b=1$ is co-ordinate axes intercepts form of a straight line . So the line cuts the $x,y$ axes at$ (\frac12, \frac{-2}{7})=(0.5,-0.28)$ approx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from

$$\frac{4x}{2} - \frac{7y}{2} = 1$$

recognize that you can simplify the fraction in the first term since ${4}/{2}={2}/{1}$

$$\frac{2x}{1} - \frac{7y}{2} = 1$$

then observe that $z=\frac{1}{1/z}$ for any $z\neq 0$. Also, $\frac{1}{a/b}=\frac{b}{a}$ if both $a\ne 0$ and $b\ne 0$. This allows you to conclude that

$$\frac{2}{1}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2/1}}=\frac{1}{{1}/{2}}$$
$$\frac{7}{2}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{7/2}}=\frac{1}{{2}/{7}}$$
therefore

$$\frac{2x}{1} - \frac{7y}{2} = \frac{x}{1/2} - \frac{y}{2/7} = \frac{x}{1/2} + \frac{y}{-2/7}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

The result is a consequence of the following two properties 
$$-\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a}{-b}=\frac{-a}{b}$$
and
$$\frac{b}{c/a}=\frac{b}{c(1/a)}=\frac{b}{c}\cdot\frac{1}{(1/a)}=\frac{b}{c}\cdot a=\frac{ab}{c}$$
when you apply them to the second term of your answer you get:
$$-\frac{7y}{2}=\frac{7y}{-2}=\frac{y}{(-2/7)}$$
which is the book's result.